# Inequalities in weak maximum uniformly elliptic operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations

As is well known that if $L=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}(x)\partial_{ij}+\sum_ib_i(x)+c(x)$ such that $a_{ij}$'s satisfy uniformly elliptic conditions and $c(x)\geq0$ on $U$, and if $u\in C^2(U)\cap C(\bar{U})$ such that $Lu\geq0$, then one has
$$
\max_{\bar{U}}u(x)\leq \max_{\partial{U}}u^+
$$
where $u^+=\max(u,0)$. Now my question is: why is there a "$\leq$" instead of an "$=$"? I checked the proof as follows:

Let $V=\{x\in U \mid u(x)>0\}$, then one has $\max_{\bar{V}}u=\max_{\partial{V}}u$ since $(L-c)u\geq0$ on $V$ and one can impose the weak maximum principle for $V$. Then $\partial{V}\subset\{x\in\partial U \mid u(x)>0\}\cup\{u(x)=0\}$, so one would have $\max_{\partial{V}}u\leq \max_{\partial U}u^+$. But my question is: why would this be a "$\leq$" instead of a "=" since maximum of $u$ on $\partial V$ should be positive (otherwise contradiction would occur), which is just $\max_{\partial U}u^+$? Where did it go wrong in my argument? Is there any counterexample to illustrate the necessity of "$<$"? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It could happen that $V=\emptyset$.

Example. Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ and $L=d^2/dx^2$; consider the equation $Lu=0$ which is $u''=0$, with BCs $u(0)=u(1)=-1$, then $u=-1$ and $u^+=0$, so the inequality is strict.